# LLL preprocessing/optimization issue

Tags: evm, compilation, lll

I have written a simple nested macro in LLL, but I can't get it to reduce to the simplest expression when calling the compiler with the optimization option. My macro looks like this:

```
(def 'mcopy (pos loc length) (codecopy (sub (mul pos 0x2) length) loc length))
```

Reading the [LLL compiler documentation](https://lll-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lll_reference.html#macro-definition-def), it seems as though invocation of the above with constants should produce a reduced assembly expression with constants, like `codecopy(x, b, c)`, and not `codecopy(sub(mul(a, 0x2), c), b, c)` as I see in the disassembled bytecode. I've read elsewhere that not all optimizations are guaranteed to occur, but I was wondering if there was a simple way to fix this, aside from writing my own preprocessor on the `.lll` source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the optimiser is sometimes not as effective on LLL code as on Solidity, but in this case I'm seeing a good effect from the constant expression folding:

```
> lllc --version
LLLC, the Lovely Little Language Compiler
Version: 0.4.20-develop.2017.12.5+commit.4cad0b22.Linux.g++

> cat optimiser_0.lll 
(seq
  (def 'mcopy (pos loc length) (codecopy (sub (mul pos 0x2) length) loc length))
  (mcopy 0x10 0x02 0x03))

> lllc -a optimiser_0.lll 
  codecopy(sub(mul(0x10, 0x2), 0x3), 0x2, 0x3)

> lllc -a -o optimiser_0.lll 
  codecopy(0x1d, 0x2, 0x3)
```

Now, this is as simple a context as possible, and your context will be more complex. This may impede the optimiser. If you can provide a minimum example that the optimiser fails to handle I'll take a look.

Comment: You're right. I realized that I was using the American English "optimize" as a flag, and it was failing silently. It works in my context too now.